# In my rails application i am using action mailer to send mails to users. to track the mail if it is opened or clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ahoy

To track if the mail is opened or clicked  i am using ahoy_email.

class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
 track utm_campaign: "boom" 
 default from: 'myemailid'

```
def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'linkofmywebsite'
    track user: user
    mail(to: @user.email,  subject: 'Welcome to My Site')
end
```

opened is working fine, but clicked is showing nil in the table even after i clicked the link in email. Any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the link is generated correctly specially the data-skip-click attribute.

```
<a data-skip-click="true" href="...">Can't touch this</a>
```